# Is it possible to split a set of recursive functions into 2 files in OCaml?

Tags: recursion, makefile, ocaml

I have a very very long file which contains a set of recursive functions. The recursion is necessary and the code is effective as well. But I just want to split the file into 2 or more files to have a better readability. But I don't see how we could split `let rec ... and ...` in OCaml...

Does anyone know if OCaml provides any mechanism (e.g., a way to specify interfaces or write `makefile`) to do so?

The very very long file may look like:

```
let rec f1 () =
  ...
  f7 (); (* f7 is called only once by all the functions in the file *)
  f2 ();
  ...
and f2 () =
  ...
  f1 ();
...
and f7 () =
  ...
  f1 (); 
  ...
```

Comment: Could you please shed some light on the context of this problem? I'm just curious: if it's some kind of auto-generated code, then why bother at all?

Comment: It is not auto-generated code, I have written these functions myself...

Comment: How long is that file? If it is manually written, I would not split it (because you might lose both efficiency & readability).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way: mutually recursive functors. See [this](http://web.mit.edu/16.399/www/project/OCaml/programs/separate-compilation/doc/separate-compilation.pdf) great article on separate compilation in OCaml and [this](https://www.tildedave.com/2011/05/23/mutually-recursive-modules-in-ocaml-and-why-you-might-care.html) inspiring article which provides the main idea.

Here is an example. I've created 4 interface mli-files:

```
$ ls *.mli
Make_moduleA.mli  Make_moduleB.mli  ModuleA.mli  ModuleB.mli
```

and 3 implementation files:

```
$ ls *.ml
Make_moduleA.ml  Make_moduleB.ml  main.ml
```

Here is the interface files' contents:

```
(* ModuleA.mli *)
module type ModuleA = sig
   val fa : int -> unit
end

(* ModuleB.mli *)
module type ModuleB = sig
   val fb : int -> unit
end

(* Make_moduleA.mli *)
open ModuleA
open ModuleB
module type Make_moduleA_sig =
  functor (Mb : ModuleB) ->
    sig
      val fa : int -> unit
    end
module Make_moduleA : Make_moduleA_sig

(* Make_moduleB.mli *)
open ModuleA
open ModuleB
module type Make_moduleB_sig =
  functor (Ma : ModuleA) ->
    sig
      val fb : int -> unit
    end
module Make_moduleB : Make_moduleB_sig
```

And mutually recursive functors:

```
(* Make_moduleA.ml *)
open ModuleA
open ModuleB    
module type Make_moduleA_sig =
  functor (Mb : ModuleB) ->
    sig
      val fa : int -> unit
    end
module Make_moduleA_impl =
  functor (Mb : ModuleB) ->
    struct
      let rec fa (n : int) =
        if n > 0 then
          (Printf.printf "A: %d\n" n;
           Mb.fb (n - 1))
    end
module Make_moduleA = (Make_moduleA_impl : Make_moduleA_sig)

(* Make_moduleB.ml *)
open ModuleA
open ModuleB    
module type Make_moduleB_sig =
  functor (Ma : ModuleA) ->
    sig
      val fb : int -> unit
    end    
module Make_moduleB_impl =
  functor (Ma : ModuleA) ->
    struct
      let rec fb (n : int) =
        if n > 0 then
          (Printf.printf "B: %d\n" n;
           Ma.fa (n - 1))
    end    
module Make_moduleB = (Make_moduleB_impl : Make_moduleB_sig)
```

And now let's combine the modules:

```
(* main.ml *)
open ModuleA
open ModuleB
open Make_moduleA
open Make_moduleB

module rec MAimpl : ModuleA = Make_moduleA(MBimpl)
and MBimpl : ModuleB = Make_moduleB(MAimpl)

let _ =     (* just a small test *)
  MAimpl.fa 4;
  print_endline "--------------";
  MBimpl.fb 4
```

Build command sequence:

```
ocamlc -c ModuleA.mli
ocamlc -c ModuleB.mli
ocamlc -c Make_moduleA.mli
ocamlc -c Make_moduleB.mli

ocamlc -c Make_moduleA.ml
ocamlc -c Make_moduleB.ml
ocamlc -c main.ml

ocamlc Make_moduleA.cmo Make_moduleB.cmo main.cmo
```

Test results:

```
$ build.sh && ./a.out
A: 4
B: 3
A: 2
B: 1
--------------
B: 4
A: 3
B: 2
A: 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference, there is another way, without functors. You have to put functions from the other module as parameter of your functions. Example : we have `even` and `odd` defined recursively, but we want `even` to be in a module `A` and `odd` to be in a module `B`.

First file :

```
(* A.ml *)
let rec even odd n =  
  if n=0
  then true
  else 
    if n=1 
    then false
    else (odd even) (n-1) ;;
```

Second file :

```
(* B.ml *)
let rec odd even n =  
if n=1
  then true
  else 
    if n=0 
    then false
    else even odd (n-1) ;;
```

Third file :

```
(* C.ml *)
let even = A.even B.odd 
and odd  = B.odd A.even ;;
print_endline (if even 5 then  "TRUE" else "FALSE") ;;
print_endline (if odd 5 then  "TRUE" else "FALSE") ;;
```

Compilation (you must use the option `-rectypes`) :

```
ocamlc -rectypes -c A.ml 
ocamlc -rectypes -c B.ml
ocamlc -rectypes -c C.ml
ocamlc -rectypes  A.cmo B.cmo C.cmo
```

I'm not sure I would recommand that, but it works.

Comment: Beware of the great and ruthless `-rectypes`! It allows self-application (an analogous thing has been used in the answer), so the mighty Y combinator will compile too: `let y f = (fun x a -> f (x x) a) (fun x a -> f (x x) a)`.

Comment: Hey Anton. You are right. And what about `let rec f x = f x` ? How can I avoid it ? ;-)

Comment: Just use `let f x = f x` :) Incidentally (sorry, if it's obvious), you can create recursive functions in OCaml without `let rec` (because OCaml does not enforce strict positivity (e.g. Agda does that): `type boxed_fun =
  | Box of (boxed_fun -> boxed_fun)

  let nonTerminating (bf:boxed_fun) : boxed_fun =
  match bf with Box f -> f bf

  let loop = nonTerminating (Box nonTerminating)`